# Calculating time difference - TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Tags: python, pandas

So, I would like create a new column called `df["Diff"]` by getting the difference between two datetime columns. My code is, thus:

```
df["Diff"] = df["Time"] - df_target["Time"]
```

When I run this code, I get the following error-message:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
```

I have however made sure that both columns are datetime-data type using `.dtype`.
I have also checked for any integer-values in any of the columns, but cannot find any.

Here is an example of the data for the two columns:

```
df.Time

Time
2017-09-01 01:31:10.000  2017-09-01 01:31:10

df_target

Time
2017-12-01 22:17:00  2017-12-01 22:17:00
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `df["Time"]` and `df_target["Time"]` please

Comment: I just geuss that problem isn't in `- (minus)` operation because we got `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'` so maybe the data structure got some sorting or index ? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out the answer.

Since one of the dataframes had an index based on datetime, while the other had an index on integer, I used reset_index to make both dataframes have an index consisting of integers. This then let me use the above code mentioned.

```
df["Diff"] = df["Time"] - df_target["Time"]
```

Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Convert both columns with dates to `pd.to_datetime` and then perform the operation.

Comment: Hi, thank you! It still gives me the same error-message, however.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas timestamp differences returns a datetime.timedelta object. This can easily be converted into hours by using the *as_type* method, like so

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['to','fr','ans'])
df.to = [pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-24 13:03:12.050000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-27 
11:57:18.240000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-23 10:07:47.660000')]
df.fr = [pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-26 23:41:21.870000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-27 
15:38:22.540000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-23 18:50:41.420000')]
(df.fr-df.to).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

to yield,

```
0    58
1     3
2     8
dtype: float64
```